# How do I fly with Elytra in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone, windows-10

I have already seen all related questions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 6):

You can glide with the elytra by pressing 'spacebar' while falling in the air, this will activate/open the elytra and you will start to glide.

However, you can also use rockets to propel yourself forward and increase your speed when gliding with the elytra.

[image: Firework rocket]

You can craft rockets with longer flight time, using these with the elytra will also keep your increased speed from the rockets longer, but unless you have lots of gunpowder it's not worth crafting the increased duration ones:

[image: Firework rocket duration 2]

[image: Firework rocket duration 3]

Comment: why is this downvoted? its correct, +1